# Wrong view count bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently got a Notable Question badge for [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238/what-are-your-favorite-programming-related-movies-documentaries) question. My profile says it has more than 3k views, but on the question page it shows less than that.

Answer (score 4):

The value reported on the question page (2,765 times) is accurate (subject to caching).

The value on your profile page is an approximation, rounded to the nearest unit of 10, 100 or in this case 1,000. If you hover over the value a tooltip should pop up with the correct value - 2766 views.

The values won't be 100% accurate due to caching, but should be within few views depending on how often the question is getting viewed.